# Selenium error' list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://www.suwon.go.kr/sw-www/www01/www01-01.jsp?q_tabs=open')
driver.implicitly_wait(3)
content = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(content)
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dateType"]'))
dropdown.select_by_index(4)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="searchBtn"]').click()


complaint_list = []
contents_list = []

def complaint_Scraping():
    for i in range(1,78):
        titles = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'tbody > tr > td.left')        
        for complaint in titles:
            name = BeautifulSoup(complaint.text, "html.parser")
            complaint_list.append(name)
        a = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,' tbody > tr > td.left > a')
        
        for content in a:
            content.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            ancient_html = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txt"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
            content = BeautifulSoup(ancient_html.text, "html.parser")             
            contents_list.append(content)                    
            driver.back()
        
complaint_Scraping()
```

i dont'know what's wrong in here
I can get all the titles, but It's not working if I try to get contents of the titles. first page may possible, but other things can't, please let me solve the problem.

Comment: Your content xpath has a very similar  xpath to the content.. without an example I don't know if its real, but it seems odd. Why would your content be found in the same location as your header.

Answer (score 0):

```
ancient_html = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="txt"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]')
content = BeautifulSoup(ancient_html.text, "html.parser")
```

`find_elements()` returns a *list* of elements.  `ancient_html` is a list.

Comment: Would you notice me the right solution?

Comment: That depends what results you were expecting.  Did you expect one element to be found, or more than one?

Comment: I expected more than one

Comment: @JohnGordon `titles` is a list while `complaint` should be a single web element so `.text` can be applied on it...

Comment: @filmlie If you expect more than one result, then presumably you would want a sub-loop to process all the results.